# changed route map not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I set my app's route map as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admininstrator", action = "Login", id = 
            UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

but after some while I just changed my mind to modify my controller name to admin as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Login", id = 
            UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and rebuilt and published my app but I can't get to localhost/admin/login
and the previous route map works! `localhost/administrator/login` why?

Comment: did you got any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second route points to the `AdminController`, if that controller doesn't exist (check in the Controllers folder) it will throw an exception.

Remane your `AdministratorController` to `AdminController`

or

change the route to point back to the `AdministratorController`